# Managing long lived named branches in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, branch

So I'm using mercurial for a project of mine, I'm the only developer.
I usually use the default branch for actual developing, I use some short lived branches for new-features, and that's fine: I create them, write the new feature and if it works good enough, I merge that branch in the default branch and never use it again.
But I'd like to write documentation in a different branch, since I don't really want to "pollute"  the default branch with docs commits.

After I have written enough documentation for the stuff I have in the default branch I merge the `docs` branch in the main one. BUT after a while I'd like to use the `docs` branch again, and I have to pull the changes from the main one, or create another new branch.

What's the best workflow to deal with this? Is my approach entirely wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing documents in source control is a little bit strange. If the documents are binary (.doc/.docx/.xlsx), Hg will not be able to merge them. If you're storing .html, .xml, or some plain text format then it will do a slightly better job. There are a few open source systems that will allow you to use Hg and provide separate document management ([Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/), for one)

Assuming you've just merged `docs` into `default` you can continue using the `docs` branch by doing this:

```
> hg update docs   # update to the docs branch
> hg merge default # merge default into docs branch
(do some work)
> hg commit -m "adding new things to docs branch"
(merge into default when ready)
```

By merging `default` into `docs`, you're making sure that `docs` has all changes that existed on `default`. Performing a subsequent commit on `docs` will effectively allow you to continue working on that branch. Another way to say this is that merging is directional in Hg - if you want `docs` to be up to date with `default`, you've got to perform that merge explicitly.

Comment: The documentation is written in sphinx, which uses plain text (rtf), so no problem about binary files.

Answer (score 0):

To start using the docs branch again from a child of your merge with the original docs branch, simply change your working copy to the branch and commit to it.

If you have changes on the docs branch then you need to merge before you can commit.